# Is it possible to slow down a PHP cURL request

Tags: php, curl

This is probably the opposite of what is usually asked, but is there anyway to actually make a cURL request slower and make the loading process last longer? I've searched and couldn't find any solutions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: through a few `sleep()`'s in to the mix. probably a better answer if you explain why you want this

Comment: @Dagon I just want to slow down a request because it has to be initiated before I do something else, but it can't load until that other thing is finished, if that makes sense. Could you elaborate on your answer? Where would I put the sleep() after or before the request? Thanks!

Comment: no it really doesn't make sense - sorry ;(

Comment: @Dagon well either way, can you show me how you would use sleep to slow down the cURL request? It seems to me that sleep would just wait for the next thing in the script, not slow down the request.

Comment: well i guess that depends on your definition of "slow down the request" this is all to vauge

Comment: @Dagon I want to slow the load time of the page I'm making the cURL request to.

Comment: I agree with Dagon. The only way you can slow the execution of a PHP script is to tell it to wait with the `sleep` function: http://nz1.php.net/sleep

Comment: it this is nessercery just sounds like poor design of the project. enlighten as to what you are *really* doing if this is not the case

Comment: [Do yu know teh The Slow Down Loop
 ??](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Slow-Down-Loop.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try *CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE*, to slow down the transfer

```
curl_setopt($cSlow,CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE,10)
```

It will work only with PHP 5.4

ps.Sorry the poor enlgish

Comment: Nice answer. From PHP's docs on this - _If a download exceeds this speed (counted in bytes per second) on cumulative average during the transfer, the transfer will pause to keep the average rate less than or equal to the parameter value. Defaults to unlimited speed._

Comment: @BrenoZan your english is good! Anyways, I seem to be getting an error that says "Request Timeout" because it took too long. Is there anyway I could make it a bit faster? Thanks

Comment: You can set CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT to a very low speed and CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME to a long time to avoid connection abortion, but.. 'Request Timeout' seems that you have a real network problem.. extend time limit with CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.. and pray for your network admin be in good mood..

Answer (score 5):

You can add a usleep in the curl progress function, if you really need to hack a slow transfer:

```
<?php

/* fast curl */
$cFast = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/users/2779152/madebydavid');
curl_setopt($cFast, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$time = microtime(true);
$result = curl_exec($cFast);
echo("fast: ".(microtime(true) - $time)."\n");


/* slow curl */
$cSlow = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/users/2779152/madebydavid');
curl_setopt($cSlow, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSlow, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($cSlow, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function() {
    usleep(100000);
    return 0;
});

$time = microtime(true);
$result = curl_exec($cSlow);
echo("slow: ".(microtime(true) - $time)."\n");
```

The first request is fast, the second slow - if you save it as curlFastSlow.php then run it, the second request should have a noticeable difference:

```
$ php -q curlFastSlow.php
fast: 0.58203315734863
slow: 1.5010859966278
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it just seems like this slows the page that makes the cURL request, not the cURL request itself.

Comment: @Grant, it worked for me, at least for an upload (i.e. a POST request with an attached file), I have been able to slow down the upload

Comment: Though this is a kind of hack, it is useful for those who have PHP version between 5.3 and 5.4.